# I am having problems with undefined names when following a pygame tutorial

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, pygame

I am following this tutorial on how to make a tile game with Pygame from here: https://qq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. When I run the program I get this error:

> NameError: name 'row' is not defined.

I have no idea what you would define row as and am also wondering whether it has something to do with the year the tutorial was made (2011 means something that worked in a newer version of python doesn't work anymore.)
The line of code which throws up this error is this:

```
for x, row in enumerate(row):
```

Comment: Hi! Please check out this link for Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code examples: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the code is this:

```
import pygame
import pygame.locals

def load_tile_table(filename, width, height):
    image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
    image_width, image_height = image.get_size()
    tile_table = []
    for tile_x in range(0, image_width/width):
        line = []
        tile_table.append(line)
        for tile_y in range(0, image_height/height):
            rect = (tile_x*width, tile_y*height, width, height)
            line.append(image.subsurface(rect))
    return tile_table

if __name__=='__main__':
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((128, 98))
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    table = load_tile_table("ground.png", 24, 16)
    for x, row in enumerate(table):
        for y, tile in enumerate(row):
            screen.blit(tile, (x*32, y*24))
    pygame.display.flip()
    while pygame.event.wait().type != pygame.locals.QUIT:
        pass
```

If we look at it, the loop is 

`for x, row in enumerate(table):
    for y, tile in enumerate(row):`

`row` is an iterable from the the first loop. After that, the second loop uses `row` to get each tile, and add a tile sprite.

Therefore, you meant `for x, row in enumerate(table):` instead of `for x, row in enumerate(row):`.

Comment: Thanks! But now there is a another error wherr it says screen.blit(tile, (x*32, y*24))
'NameError: name 'tile' is not defined'

Comment: `screen.blit(tile, (x*32, y*24))` should be under the loop `for y, tile in enumerate(row):` which is under `for x, row in enumerate(table):`. Essentially, just `for x, row in enumerate(table):
    for y, tile in enumerate(row):
        screen.blit(tile, (x*32, y*24))`

Comment: @James If you believe an answer for your question suits your needs, there is a check button for every answer. This notifies everyone that the question is solved, and marks your question as solved.